# How to use rex command with REST api of splunk curl as client

Tags: rest, api, splunk

i am trying to Extract new field from raw data by regular expression(rex command).My regular expression is working fine in splunk web search bar and getting results. But not not working with REST api curl as client.

i want to extract a field from a csv data set train.csv and want to give it name as "numbers"

```
curl -u admin:password -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="search source=train.csv|rex field=_raw '^(?:\[^\"\\n\]*\"){2},\\w+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+,(?P<numbers>\[^,\]+)'| top numbers"
```

by executing this command i got sid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<response>
 <sid>1548238904.70</sid>
```

by after asking for result i am getting error

```
curl -u admin:password -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/1548238904.70/results

Error in 'rex' command: The regex ''^(?:\[^\n\]*){2}' does not extract anything. It should specify at least one named group. Format: (?&lt;name&gt;...).</msg>
```

what is named group ,why its working well in splunk search bar

i want result with "number" as column or new field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your SPL itself, it appears that you've got single quotes instead of double quotes in your rex, which is known to cause issues or no results.

Try the following approach of escaping double quotes instead:

```
$ curl -u 'username:password' -k https://dummy.splunk.url/services/search/jobs -d search="| stats count | eval foo=\"bar\" | rex field=foo \"\w(?<named>\w*)\" | table foo named"
```

When asking for the results back, you should see the following:

```
$ curl -u 'username:password' -k https://dummy.splunk.url/services/search/jobs/1548868781.39708/results

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   315  100   315    0     0    420      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   420<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results preview='0'>
<meta>
<fieldOrder>
<field>foo</field>
<field>named</field>
</fieldOrder>
</meta>
        <result offset='0'>
                <field k='foo'>
                        <value><text>bar</text></value>
                </field>
                <field k='named'>
                        <value><text>ar</text></value>
                </field>
        </result>
</results>
```

Presuming the above approach is used, you should end up with a curl command as such:

```
curl -u admin:password -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="search source=train.csv|rex field=_raw \"^(?:\[^\"\\n\]*\"){2},\\w+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+,(?P<numbers>\[^,\]+)\"| top numbers"
```